# Using the "name" argument to group requests

Tags: python, locust

I have a working request like this:

```
 resp = self.client.get(f'/api/loadValues?tsIds={load_ts_ids_in_function}&resolution={resolution}'
                           f'&startUtc={set_from_date_load_values()}&endUtc={set_to_date_load_values()}',
                           headers={'X-API-KEY': 'xxx'})
```

But the User’s statistics are not aggregated in the Locust web-gui.

Came across this:

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#name-parameter

But how do I use the name-argument in the above code?

Comment: Are you using python-requests for your client?

Comment: I do as my example shows. Not a good idea?

Comment: You seem to be using the locust request client. Are you subclassing the HTTPUser class? If so, you can set before your request the `request_name` on the client like the documentation guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the examples in the doc you linked, you include `name='this string is what I want the stats to report as'`. So if you wanted them to be grouped as `'/api/loadValues'` you'd do:

```
resp = self.client.get(f'/api/loadValues?tsIds={load_ts_ids_in_function}&resolution={resolution}'
                       f'&startUtc={set_from_date_load_values()}&endUtc={set_to_date_load_values()}',
                       headers={'X-API-KEY': 'xxx'}, name='/api/loadValues')
```